# Windows 10 Error after XP MBR fix

Tags: windows, boot, windows-xp, mbr, bitlocker

Today I repaired a Windows XP drive, but couldn't boot into it. So I thought that fixing the MBR from an XP USB would help.

Once I fixed the MBR, the problem still continued. I tried booting into my BitLocker-encrypted Windows 10 drive, but it did not ask me for a password and just said 'installing updates' and then restarted.

It did this multiple times.

I tried to use CMD on a Windows 10 USB, but it never asked me for the recovery key of the drive thus it wasn't recognized.

I then booted into Linux Mint off of a USB and tried to look through my drive, only to be horrified. My computer had somehow changed to an XP folder structure.

(E.g., No Program Files (x86); Users -----> My Documents and settings; Windows -----> WINDOWS; etc.)

I'm afraid I may have messed up my drive permanently, but am hoping to find a solution here. Can anyone help me?

Comment: It does indeed sound like your actions have caused what is likely an unrecoverable data loss. Are you sure you are not simply looking at the Windows XP drive?  Linux has almost no support for BitLocker drives.

Comment: @Ramhound Unfortunately, no. The XP drive had a different username.

Comment: @Ramhound So I rebooted a couple of times and it seems it restored to an earlier restore point. When I say early, I mean March 2020 early. There was a folder called 'Sys~Restore' or something and it contained the following XML: https://pastebin.com/gqX2vADh. Please tell me if I can recover my data!

Comment: At this point your data is gone since you used a restore point.

Comment: Well, it seems like it was my own fault. I plugged into the wrong drive. Sorry for causing you a heart attack @Ramhound.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author made a mistake and connected the incorrect drive to the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like it was my own fault. I plugged into the wrong drive. Sorry for causing you a heart attack @Ramhound.